# Windows crashes my GPU

Tags: graphics-card, crash, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-artifacts

This issue started 3 days ago.
Upon the sign-in screen, my screen starts flickering and I see weird glitchy graphical artifacts in the loading wheel. After a little while, my GPU would crash and my screen would show "No analog input detected"

While DDU'ing (aka cleanly reinstalling graphics driver) does help, but it's not helpful in the long run. Games would run but will crash after a while. Things will keep getting worse in minutes and then eventually being not able to boot into windows.

I can however boot into safe mode and work perfectly fine.

***Hardware:***

- Windows 10 (21H1)
- Nvidia Quadro K600
- Core 2 Duo E7500
- 6GBs of DDR3

***FAQ:***

**- Did you Overclock?**

Hell NO! nor I have any idea on how to do it

**- Could be temperature problem, are all fans working?**

Actually, I really think that its overheating a lot than usual but I didn't check the temperature through a software. But all the fans are working fine. I also cleaned it up.

**- How did you install windows?**

I downloaded the media creation tool. Booted into the USB, formatted the drive, and then installed in that one. I didn't remove any drive. Everything was working fine till last night.

**- Did you modify windows?**

No, not at all. This is a pure and clean windows installation. No modification.

**- Whats your Power Supply Model?**

I have H255PD-00 Power Supply thats 300 watt

**- How have you connected your GPU?**

Direct connection with the motherboard. Plugged onto a PCI slot.

**- Are you using the power supply cables that came with your power supply or third party ones? Are you using any extensions? Are you using any adapters?**

I'm using default cables that come with the power supply. No extensions nor adapters.

**- What DIMM slots are your sticks in and how many sticks do you have?**

I only have 2 slots both filled up. 4GB stick is farther away from CPU and I got 2 sticks ( 4GB and 2GB ) Unplugging RAM and Switching slots doesnt help.

Comment: What is your display adapter and what is its installed driver?

Comment: Update BIOS, restart, and the reinstall the video driver.

Comment: @harrymc I have Nvidia Quadro K600 and I have installed version 466 and I also tried previous versions but no success :(

Comment: Your recommended driver version seems to be [version 426.78](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/160351/en-us).

Comment: @John I really don't think that BIOS can have an impact on the graphics card while in Windows and the problem just showed itself 3 days ago.
However, I can be completely wrong here until a tech-savvy comes along.

Comment: @harrymc I would surely give that a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late but if someone is still looking for an answer with similar problem, it was an issue with my graphics card. It was its last breaths before it died.

If you ever have graphical issues, change your graphics adapter (remove dedicated and use integrated/igpu). If the issue doesn't persist, your card may be on its way to death.